# Changing button created with <button> text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button

My code looks like this

in .html

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggle()" id="toggleButton">more ⇓</button>
```

.js

```
function toggle(){
document.getElementById("toggleButton").innnerHTML="less ⇑";}
```

The button appears in my page with the more text, but clicking the button does not do anything.

In  I do have reference

```
<script src="button.js"></script>
```

And the name of my javescript file is button.js

Comment: typo error innnerHTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `innerHTML` not `innnerHTML`

```js
document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerHTML="less ⇑";
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="toggle()" id="toggleButton">more ⇓</button>
```

Comment: Typo should not be answer, comment place is enough for typo mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
<input onclick="toggle()" type="button" value="more ⇓" id=myButton1"></input>
```

Js:

```
    function toggle()
    {
        if (this.value=="more ⇓") 
             {this.value = "less ⇑";}
        else 
             {this.value = "more ⇓";}
    }
```